# How to count letter 'u' in given .txt file

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion

I have a grid which, you can see in the image. Firstly, I needed to find how many different connections of letter 'u' are there. I used a youtube explanation video where they talked about Number Of Islands from LeetCode. Using +- same strategy I found that there's 2 different connections of letter 'u'. The first connection contains 22 letter 'u' and the second connection contains 14 letter 'u'. My Output shoud look like this 2 (Different connections, which I already found), 22(dont have this), 14(dont have this

InPut1 :
[Input1 data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZEnp.png)
6 and 15 are dimensions.
OutPut1 :
2
22
14
InPut2 :
[Input2 data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbKGj.png)
OutPut2 :
1
5

Now , I need to write an algorithm to calculate how many 'u' letters does each connection has. For example the first connection (In Input1 photo it's colored red) has 22 letter 'u' connected to each other. The second connection (In Input1 photo it's colored pink) has 14 letter 'u' connected to each other.

Also, I can't use linq.

In this code you can see that I already found that there are 2 different connections.

I also wrote a code to find how many letters 'u' does each connection contains method called : public static int CountLetterUInConnection(char[][] grid), but it doesn't work.

Maybe someone can spot my mistake and show me the right way? Or maybe I'm doing it all wrong and I need to redo it?

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = "App_Data/Map.txt";
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path));
            int Width = int.Parse(lines[0]);
            int Height = int.Parse(lines[1]);
            Label4.Text = "Width: " + Width.ToString();
            Label5.Text = "Height: " + Height.ToString();
            for (int i = 2; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                var newRow = new TableRow();
                var newCell = new TableCell();
                newCell.Text = lines[i];
                newRow.Cells.Add(newCell);
                Table1.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
        }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = "App_Data/Map.txt";
        string map = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path));
        char[][] grid = GetGridGFromMap(map);
        int NumberOfMoles = TaskUtils.LettersIsU(grid);
        int Count = TaskUtils.CountLetterUInConnection(grid);
       // Label1.Text = "Cave count: " + NumberOfMoles.ToString();
        Label1.Text = Count.ToString();

        
    }

    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private char[][] GetGridGFromMap(string map)
    {
        string[] lines = map.Split('\n');
        char[][] grid = new char[lines.Length][];
        for(int i =0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            grid[i] = lines[i].ToCharArray();
        }
        return grid;
    }
}
class TaskUtils
{
     
    public static int LettersIsU(char[][] grid)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].Length; j++)
            {
                if (grid[i][j] == 'u')
                {
                    count++;
                    SetCountedLetters(grid, i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    private static void SetCountedLetters(char[][] grid, int i, int j)
    {
        if (i < 0 || i >= grid.Length || j < 0 || j >= grid[i].Length || grid[i][j] == 'z')
            return;
        grid[i][j] = 'z';
        SetCountedLetters(grid, i + 1, j);
        SetCountedLetters(grid, i - 1, j);
        SetCountedLetters(grid, i, j + 1);
        SetCountedLetters(grid, i, j - 1);
    }
    public static int CountLetterUInConnection(char[][] grid)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].Length; j++)
            {
                if (grid[i][j] == 'u')
                {
                    count++;
                    if ((i - 1 >= 0 && grid[i - 1][j] == 'u') || (i + 1 < grid.Length && grid[i + 1][j] == 'u')
                        || (j - 1 >= 0 && grid[i][j - 1] == 'u') || (j + 1 < grid[i].Length && grid[i][j + 1] == 'u'))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}`
```

Comment: [Not the first time today we have seen this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75454103/1070452)

Comment: Me and my friend are working on this, but I decided to give some more details so it would be easier to understand to others,

Comment: In `SetCountedLetters()`, count each time you do `grid[i][j] = 'z';`  for each island.

Comment: @KenY-N what do you mean?

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp We can delete or remove the other post if that's needed

Comment: @TLyrics - It'd be awesome if you posted the grids as text. Images are hard to work with.

Comment: @TLyrics: for what it's worth, you did a much better job of describing the problem

Comment: @Enigmativity If you still need grids I can send you.

Comment: @Flydog57 Maybe you have some ideas how could I fix that, my head is blowing up :D

Comment: @TLyrics - Don't ask, just post the grids as code. It'll make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this were me, I'd refactor your `int LettersIsU(char[][] grid)` to become `int[] LettersIsU(char[][] grid)` whereby the length of the array is the number of contiguous groups found and each value in the array is the count in each group.

I'd do something like this:

```
public static int[] LettersIsU(char[][] grid)
{
    int[][] found = new int[grid.Length][];
    Dictionary<int, int> count = new();
    void SetCountedLetters(char[][] grid, int i, int j)
    {
        if (i < 0 || i >= grid.Length || j < 0 || j >= grid[i].Length || found[i][j] != 0 || grid[i][j] != 'u')
            return;
        found[i][j] = count.Count;
        count[count.Count] += 1;
        SetCountedLetters(grid, i + 1, j);
        SetCountedLetters(grid, i - 1, j);
        SetCountedLetters(grid, i, j + 1);
        SetCountedLetters(grid, i, j - 1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.Length; i++)
        found[i] = new int[grid[i].Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.Length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].Length; j++)
            if (grid[i][j] == 'u' && found[i][j] == 0)
            {
                count[count.Count + 1] = 0;
                SetCountedLetters(grid, i, j);
            }
    int[] output = new int[count.Count];
    for (int k = 0; k < count.Count; k++)
        output[k] = count[k + 1];
    return output;
}
```